# Extremely bad situation with VB 2010 express

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crash

I have been having errors with intellisense on vb 2010 express. I tried editing code and intellisense crashed it. I tried disabling intellisense, and that crashed it too. It has gotten worse, and is now at the point where it crashes my computer when I open vb. I've tried repairing it, and it said it couldn't install Microsoft Error Reporting. I tried to uninstall it, and it said there was a problem with a .dll and told me to see if I could access it. The dll exists, and I was able to easily find it. I've tried restarting the computer and uninstalling it, and that did nothing. Please help me, this is extremely aggravating.

Comment: try to install in other pc. if you have found is everything okay. you can conclude now that your pc is the problem or else the installer.

Comment: I have it on another computer, and it works just fine. Nothing bad happens with the other one. It's just this one. And this only started happening recently.

Comment: mhmm and then try to clean up your pc or reformat `:D`

Comment: problem with that is that this is a school computer. I don't want to mess anything up. And I have no idea how to reformat a computer anyway, and if I attempted that, I'd probably end up making the laptop explode.

Answer (score 1):

The best bet if to uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio. Try uninstalling after a fresh system boot. If that doesn't work, try booting in Safe Mode and uninstalling. If that doesn't work, try re-installing with the "repair" option. If that doesn't work, as a last resort you might be able to reinstall a second copy of Visual Studio on the computer and use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would reinstall the entire computer. 
Reinstall windows and go from there.
No repair, no fix. Clean install.

Comment: That's what I'm trying, but now it's saying it has to reformat the hard drive, because it couldn't find that. This is getting to be not just about VB, imo.